# Picasso не отображает картинку

Tags: android

Picasso не отображает картинку

```
Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
            .load(Constants.PREVIEW_VIDEO_IMG_URL + item.getId() + Constants.FORMAT_JPG)
            .fit()
            .into(holder.mIntroCourseImg);
```

Я проверял в ответ получаю некую ссылку на картинку. Но в приложении картинка не выводиться. Почему?

Ошибок никаких нет

---

URL ссылка
 http://cdn0.knowledgecity.com/opencontent/courses/previews/SAF1001.jpg

Comment: А url в `Constants.PREVIEW_VIDEO_IMG_URL + item.getId() + Constants.FORMAT_JPG` валидный? Может где-то слеш затерялся?

Comment: скиньте пример Вашего Url на выходе.
Скорее всего, он некорректен

Comment: Все в порядке с сылкой я же говорю. скинул ее сверху

Comment: @gil9red, Через log вывел. Ссылка нормально выводиться

Comment: КОРОЧЕ. Даже если даю прямую ссылку то не рабоатет. НО ЕСЛИ Даю локальную ссылку в load то рабоатет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашей ссылке, изображение открывается по `https`. В `Picasso` Вы используете `http`.

Т.е., поменяйте в `Constants.PREVIEW_VIDEO_IMG_URL` `http` на `https`

(В моём семпле Ваш кейс заработал после данной правки)

Comment: Спасибо. Вчера сам ток наткнулся на это. И ведь и не поймешь в чем подвох то